# Why is not there the peerconnection_client for mac in libjingle?

Tags: webrtc, libjingle

I am curious why there is not the peerconnection_client for mac in libjingle example.

Is the implementation in mac different or the based library for peer-to-peer cannot be used in mac os x?

Answer (score 2):

There is none available officially. But I would use the below readme to create one yourself. Basically it gives you instructions on how to build peerconnection objc implementation on MacOSX and iOS. Specifically you might be able to convert AppRTCDemo for iOS into a MacOSX app with not too much extra code

https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/source/browse/trunk/talk/app/webrtc/objc/README